# powershell add user to the domain

Tags: powershell, dns, addition

I'm not really familiar with Powershell and I'm trying to use it to automate some manual work. I was able to get 'rename computer' and 'addComputerTotheDomain' scripts working but got stuck in this part below.I did a lot of research but I could't understand a lot the scripts that people post (like the meaning of acronyms [ADSI] OU...and so on)  Here are the steps:

- Login with the administrator account that you joined the domain with
- Go to Control Panel --> User Accounts  Click "Manage User Accounts"
- Click "Add"  User name: myUserName Domain: MYDOMAIN
- Select "Administrator" for level of access
- After clicking "Finish" click on the Advanced tab of the User Accounts window
- Uncheck "Require users to press Ctrl+alt+Delete" check box
- Click the "Advanced" button under "Advanced user management"
- Click into the Users section under "Local Users and Groups"
- Right click the Administrator account and click "Set Password", set as myPassword
- Double click the Administrator account
- "Password never expires" should be the only box checked in
  the list on the General tab. "Account is disabled" is frequently
  checked, uncheck it.
- Click OK, close all windows, and log off. You can now login as mydomain.com\myUserName with myPassword as the password.

any help would be appreciated to get the first step started (add user name).
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog, it should help you out http://blogs.technet.com/b/benp/archive/2007/03/05/benp-s-basic-guide-to-managing-active-directory-objects-with-powershell.aspx